# React con vite y docker no funciona

Tags: docker

Soy nuevo en los contenedores con **Docker** estoy intentando hacer un contenedor de react con vite en windows.

Estoy creando la imgen desde un *Dockerfile*

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 5173
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host"]
```

Construyo la imagen `docker build . -t react-vite`

Construyo el contenedor `docker run -p 5173:5173 react-vite`

Hasta aqui funciona bien pero cuando intento poner un volumen con `docker run -v D:\Workspace\Docker\Practicas\tutorial-volume:/app -p 5173:5173 react-vite` me lanza error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: saludos, estas utilizando windows o linux? wsl? porque según el error, deberías instalar el esbuild  de linux y no de windows

Comment: Si no lo mencione, estoy utilizadon windows

Comment: prueba descargando wsl de ubuntu, desde la tienda y ahi realizas el proceso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo, el problema es que el proyecto de vite fue creado con un sistema operativo windows cuando copiamos la carpeta node_modulos da problemas ya el contenedor corre en linux.

Al construir el contenedor debemos excluir la carpeta node_modules de que esta en nuestro host para el contenedor use la sulla.

```
docker run -p 5173:5173 -v D:\Workspace\Docker\Practicas\tutorial-volume:/app -v /app/node_modules/ react-vite
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]A mi tampoco le funciona solo con VITE, probé con react npm y me cargo  normal. Aqui en la imagen arriba en el puerto que le puse 3700 no carga y abajo muestra mi docker desktop que si copio los archivos. ¿Que puede estar pasando, aunque vite por default se ejecuta en el puerto 5173?.

> #Node
> FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
>
> WORKDIR /usr/src/app
>
> COPY package*.json ./
>
> RUN npm install
>
> COPY . .
>
> EXPOSE 3700
>
> CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta a la pregunta, te recomiendo que si tienes otro problema formules otra pregunta, lee [ask]